# fractional ratings with angular bootstrap directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there a way to display fractional ratings from decimal numbers with angular directives for Bootstrap?

```
<rating ng-model="ranking_level" max="5" readonly="true" ng-init="ranking_level = 2.4"/>
```

So far I have achieved only plain stars display ★★★☆☆